# Look for Value in Multiple Keys with JSONPath

Tags: jsonpath

With JSONPath, how can you extract a single value from a list of known keys?

For example, I want to write one JSON path expression that can extract `Sean` from all three of these JSON documents:

1. `{ "firstName": "Sean" }`
2. `{ "first_name": "Sean" }`
3. `{ "first_name": "Sean", "firstName": "Sean" }`

This example is a little contrived, but I have an actual use case that requires this behavior.

The best I can come up with is the expression `$.firstName,first_name` which will work for #1 and #2 but returns an array for #3 — and I just want the first value that matches.

Basically, I’m looking for a JSONPath extract expression that simulates this JavaScript code:

```
json.firstName || json.first_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like below :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get json path using the index .Whn I'm using rest-assured I always use something similar to below code to extract values from my json response .

```
Response response=given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).get("http://localhost:3000/posts");
    JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
    String fn1 = jsonPathEvaluator.get("firstName[0]");
    String fn_1=jsonPathEvaluator.get("first_name[0]");
    String fn2=jsonPathEvaluator.get("firstName[1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all pair to dict and then extract your values or if you need only values you can use set structure to store keys and separate list to values.